# Interpolation of the metric tensor

Tags: riemannian-geometry, interpolation

I am currently facing the following problem. I have a Riemannian manifold, where the metric is only known at certain points. Are there some standard strategy to interpolate the metric in other points of the manifold?

Thanks for your answers,
Emmanuel